# RegEx with independent group

Tags: c#, regex

I have RegEx below which looks for predefined html tags and their properties like src|href|action. It contain groups which parse string like this

Parsed string:

```
<a data-mydata href="myUrl"></a>
```

Extracted groups:

```
[0] {<a data-mydata href="myUrl">}
[1] {}
[2] {<a data-mydata href="}
[3] {myUrl}
[4] {">}
[5] {} //<- Empty result, the data-mydata is not read
```

RegEx:

```
(?<pre><(?:script|img|a|area|link|base|input|frame|iframe|form)\\b.*?(?:src|href|action)\\s*=\\s*[\"']\\s*)(?<url>.+?)(?<post>\\s*[\"'][^>]*?>)|(?<data>(data-mydata))
```

The problem is that I want to check for attribute `data-mydata` but `group 5` return empty result `{}`. `data-mydata` attribute is optional but I need to know is `data-mydata` exists or not.

Comment: Why aren't you using the HtmlAgilityPack to parse HTML? I would say that would be a much easier way.

Comment: This is not my decision and I can't change it, I must use RegEx.

Comment: With HtmlAgilityPack, you could collect all the information about the tags and their attributes, and check whatever you need. Really, it is quicker and safer N times than trying with regex. Should I suggest a HtmlAgilityPack-based solution?

Answer (score 0):

When you have a match you can retreive group 5 and see if it is a success

```
match.Groups[5].Success
```

or named

```
match.Groups["data"].Success
```

Also make sure the preceding group is not greedily matching to the end tag (), add a ? to the end of the group so it stops at the end of the start tag

```
(?<tag><a\s(?<data>data-mydata)?)?.*(?<end><\/a>)
```

this works to match the 3 groups within, notice one group is nested withing the other as an optional match (?)

```
<a data-mydata href="myUrl"></a>
```

matches

```
tag     [0-15]  `<a data-mydata `
data    [3-15]  `data-mydata `
end     [28-32] `</a>`
```

and

```
<a href="myUrl"></a>
```

matches

```
tag [0-3]   `<a `
end [16-20] `</a>`
```

Comment: The problem that Group 5 always return null. I think I use |(?<data>(data-mydata)) incorrectly.

Comment: use the name its a named group so match.Groups["data"].Success

Comment: As expected with match.Groups["data"].Success I get False because something wrong with RegEx and Group "data" is not captures.

Comment: Could you post an example at https://regex101.com ? I have tried your suggestion but it fails again, maybe I misunderstood something.

Comment: doing now, the parsed string in your question returning one match (data) for 'data-mydata', what is your complete string

Comment: you have an or | operator between the groups, so it will match the first 4 groups or the 5 group not all, you need to remove the |

Comment: Sorry but it do not works, could you post full example?

Comment: Any luck with your regex?

Comment: Could you post the full RegEx, use my regex and add your suggested?

Comment: Your solution do not works if data-mydata placed at the end of tag like this <a href="myUrl" data-mydata></a>

Comment: Correct, need to use lookaheads http://regular-expressions.mobi/lookaround.html I will update my answer soon